# Extract specification list from text (unknown format)

Tags: php, text, information-extraction

How can I extract a specification from product description which is of unknown format (sometimes it is unordered list, sometimes it's br-element etc.) but it ALWAYS looks same way on front.

The visual is like:

> Some description text, somethimes it is one sentence, sometimes more..
>
> == sometimes here's an empty line, sometimes is not ==
>
> - spec item1
> - spec item2

Is there a way to extract that "by it's visual' in PHP?

Example:

```
<h2> desc <br>
<br>
&gt; <strong> T Shirt</strong><br>
&gt; Breathable mesh fabric<br>
&gt; Reflective detail<br>
&gt; Flat lock seams <br>
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What are you trying to extract? And what have you tried?

Comment: I need extract only that "specification list" and I tried: 1. extract everything after dbl br elem. - doesn't work, sometimes it's only 1, 2. tried find > char, doesn't work, sometimes it's in top text description or sometimes that list doesn't have > at start of line.. I imagine there's a way to unHTML it but let the visual format in same way and then extract it somehow.. really dont know how to move with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and filter your entries.  I've managed to get your example into an array.  It would then be a case of a little wrangling with the result:

```
<?php

$html =<<<HTML
<h2> desc </h2>
<br>
&gt; <strong> T Shirt</strong><br>
&gt; Breathable mesh fabric<br>
&gt; Reflective detail<br>
&gt; Flat lock seams <br>
HTML;

$no_html       = strip_tags($html);
$no_entities   = preg_replace('/&#?[a-z0-9]+;/i', '', $no_html);
$parts         = preg_split('/\R/', $no_entities);
$trimmed_parts = array_map('trim', $parts);
var_export($trimmed_parts);
```

Output:

```
array (
    0 => 'desc',
    1 => '',
    2 => 'T Shirt',
    3 => 'Breathable mesh fabric',
    4 => 'Reflective detail',
    5 => 'Flat lock seams',
)
```

Comment: The filtering of entities could be destructive, if say you have encoded ampersands within the descriptions.  Alternatively you could anchor your matches to the beginning of the line if that's the case, or throw away the general rule for something more specific.

Comment: Hoping if you have html lists, that you have newlines.  Otherwise those could be more work.  You may need different recipes.  Have a go, and come back if it's a problem with example input, what you've tried and desired output.

Comment: if you can extend that function to translate ul>li list to that format this is extracting, it will be 100% right answer

Comment: It could well work with no tweaking on ul li lists.  If however there are no line returns between lis it may not.  Instead, you may need to explode on the ul, or li tags, and then strip in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with file_get_contents() and some regex processing. Please  ensure you have proper settings enabled in PHP.ini (fopen URL wrappers)

Refer:
    http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Sample code:

```
<?php

$page = file_get_contents('Provide your url here');

preg_match("/regex pattern here/", $page, $agent_name);

// display agent name matches
print_r($agent_name)
```

Personal suggestion - Using python will simpler the process. Lot of packages are available already for this purpose. Eg- bs4

Comment: I have that description in my database, so I don't have to get that content and this question is just about that regex you don't provide..